# Xub 16.04 There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'failed to connect to server'

Tags: printing, localhost

I have tried many many many things, uninstalled cups from command line, synaptic, software center, dozens of times. right now it shows as installed in all those places, and the most up to date.

Found that `/etc/init.d/cups` was not there, so copied from working machine to there.

checked `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`  and it checked out perfect with an identical machine with no problems.

restarted cups, service, computer many times.

localhost:631 doesnt give anything at all, just unavailable screen
"printers" in settings menu gives the typical

> printing service not available. Start the service on this computer or connect to another server

And the <kbd>start service</kbd> button is not able to be clicked.

Trying to connect to localhost by clicking the <kbd>connect</kbd> button I get

> **CUPS server error**
>   There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'failed to connect to server'.

I have searched high and low, and many people have kinda similar problems, but none of their solutions give the same results. What should I do?

Comment: I have the same problem and it persists even after a reinstall of CUPS Hal_V